# Compare two columns of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$get_list_cate`.

So, I want to compare values of two columns in this array.

Array `$get_list_cate`:

```
ID..................PARENT_ID.....................NAME
0                   5                             Ashe
1                   3                             Garen
2                   0                             Yasuo
4                   1                             Miss Fortune
5                   2                             Veikor
```

So, I tried to loop through this array and tried to compare all values of `id` with all values of `parent_id`. Here my code:

```
<?php foreach($get_list_cate as $item_cate):

    if($item_cate->parent_id == $item_cate->id ) :
          // some code
    endif

endforeach
?>
```

But it will like this:

```
Only 5 is values of `parent_id`     :      - compare to -      :       all values in `id`.


5  ---- 0
   ---- 1
   ---- 2
   ---- 4
   ---- 5    -> correct.
```

Stop at here. Is not two `foreach`.

It should continue with:

```
3 ----- 0
   ---- 1
   ---- 2
   ---- 4
   ---- 5
```

=> not available in this array.

```
0 ----- 0    -> correct.
   ---- 1
   ---- 2
   ---- 4
   ---- 5
```

More and more....

Comment: Do you want to compare each column with each other columns? Your problem is not clear.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Your code should work in comparing the `parent_id` with the `id` for the same item.

Comment: Youre talking abour two foreach but there is only one in your code. Aren't you confusing the two foreach values ?

Comment: @user987456321. First foreach only loop through all values in `$get_list_cate`. No include when I tried to compare `id` with `parent_id`.

Comment: You have `two foreach` and you have to compare the foreach value of first array with the foreach each value of second array right :) Am i clear with the concept

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanations:**

1. The usage of this operator called `->` which is used for getting of the objects from the array.
2. But when you are going to **loop through** the array values **which comes from the DB** you have to use the operator called `$data['DB COLUMN NAME']` to fetch the data or do what ever as you wish.
3. Where `$data` is the variable that comes in the loop.

Hence this might be code code you need to use.

> If you need to compare with `one foreach()` for the single array you get.

```
<?php 
foreach($get_list_cate as $single_item)
{
   if($single_item['id'] == $single_item['parent_id'])
    {
        // You can handle upon the condition if TRUE
    }
    else
    {
        // You can handle the FALSE Request over here
    }
}
?>
```

> If you need to compare with `Two foreach()` for the array you get.

**(E.g)** You need to compare the `ID` from the `first array` and the `PARENT_ID` from the `second array` you can use the below code.

```
<?php 
foreach($get_list_cate as $key1=>$single_item)
{
    foreach ($single_item as $key2 => $single_value) 
    {
            if($key2==$key1)    
            {
                if($single_value['parent_id'] == $single_item['id'])
                {
                    // You can handle upon the condition if TRUE
                }
                else
                {
                // You can handle the FALSE Request over here
                }           
            }
    }
}
?>
```

**Alternative Solution:**

If you have two arrays namely `$array1` and `$array2` you can perform the `array_diff()` in order to fetch out the odd one alone. It pulls out the differed value from the array if you use the `array_diff()` function.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: My problem appears at my pen. http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/zKoPAE. Need update data when clicked a tab. Have you any example like this or keyword to research? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loop

```
<?php 
  foreach($get_list_cate as $item_cate1):
      foreach($get_list_cate as $item_cate2):
          echo $item_cate1->parent_id . '----' . $item_cate2->id;
          if($item_cate1->parent_id == $item_cate2->id ):
              // some code
              echo "-> correct";
          endif
          echo "<br>";
      endforeach
  endforeach 
?>
```

Comment: Why `<?php ?>` for each line ? It's ugly.

Comment: I write PHP code with HTML. So, I filter PHP code don't remove `<?php ?>` in each line.

Answer (score 1):

Your supplied data suggests that four parent id's appear in the id column, not one. i.e. 0, 1, 2 & 5.  You can use the array_intersect function in conjunction with the array_column function to find these.

```
$parent = array_column($get_list_cate,'PARENT_ID');
$ids = array_column($get_list_cate, 'ID');

$intersect = array_intersect($parent, $ids);
```

Then simply loop through the results to present your output

Answer (score -1):

You use the `->` operator, wich is used for objects. You should use the array notation if what you called "array" `$get_list_cate` is a real array :

```
foreach($get_list_cate as $item_cate):

    if($item_cate['parent_id'] == $item_cate['id']) :
      // some code
    endif;

endforeach;
```